# Select keys and values only if there are more than 5 values that are more than 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is data that has been grouped and filtered by using spark dataframe in scala:

```
+---------------+------+--------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
|         keys  |num_1 |num_2   |num_3  |num_4 |num_5 |num_6 |num_7 |num_8 |num_9   |
+---------------+------+--------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
|              1|     0|       0|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       0|
|              2|     0|       0|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       0|
|              3|     0|     134|      0|     0|    44|   332|     0|   423|     111|
|              4|     0|     338|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       0|
|              5|     0|       0|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       0|
|              6|     0|       0|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       0|
|              7|     0|     130|      4|    11|     0|     5|  1222|     0|       0|
|              8|     0|       1|      0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|       2|
```

From the data filtered, is there a simple way to select only keys that have more than 5 values that are more than 0?

(e.g. only keys 3 and 7 will be selected together with their values out of the eight keys)

The only way i have thought about is checking through each values (num_1, num_2,...,num_9) individually, and if they are more than 0, do an increment on a variable (e.g. variable 'i'). and if the variable is more than 5 at the end of the check, select the key with the values. But this way seems long winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter condition using:

```
df.columns.tail.map(x => when(col(x) > 0, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _) >= 5
```

which converts values larger than 0 to 1, and 0 otherwise. Then use `reduce` across all the columns to count 1s per row.

---

```
df.filter(df.columns.tail.map(x => when(col(x) > 0, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _) >= 5).show

+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|keys|num_1|num_2|num_3|num_4|num_5|num_6|num_7|num_8|num_9|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   3|    0|  134|    0|    0|   44|  332|    0|  423|  111|
|   7|    0|  130|    4|   11|    0|    5| 1222|    0|    0|
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the solution. Working as intended. May i know why df.columns.tail?

Comment: `df.columns.tail` selects all column names except the first column, i.e. `key`. I assume that's the column you don't want to count in when looking at the values.